# How do I update old IDE-extension code so it doesn't use the deprecated ExptIntf and ToolsIntf units?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

I'm doing my first tests about extending the IDE but I only find old source codes which uses `ExptInft` and `ToolsIntf`, which are deprecated (Delphi 2007).

I'm looking for a newer example code or help for updating an old example.

**Here's what I did for trying to update an old example:**

I've started from [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads21/sourcecode/book/71256/Delphi%203%20%E9%AB%98%E7%BA%A7%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91%E6%8C%87%E5%8D%97/15/COMPS/PANELED.PAS__.htm) example source code:

```
unit PanelEd; 

interface 

uses 
  Classes, Forms, Windows, Dialogs, ExptIntf, ToolIntf, 
  FileCtrl, SysUtils, EditIntf, DsgnIntf; 

type 
  TPanelEditExpert = class (TIExpert) 
  public 
    function GetStyle: TExpertStyle; override; 
    function GetName: string; override; 
    function GetAuthor: string; override; 
    function GetComment: string; override; 
    function GetPage: string; override; 
    function GetGlyph: HICON; override; 
    function GetState: TExpertState; override; 
    function GetIDString: string; override; 
    function GetMenuText: string; override; 
    procedure Execute; override; 
  end; 

// custom module for the panel 
type 
  TPanelModule = class (TCustomModule) 
  public 
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override; 
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override; 
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override; 
    procedure ValidateComponent(Component: TComponent); override; 
  end; 

procedure Register; 

implementation 

uses 
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons; 

// "standard" project expert 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetStyle: TExpertStyle; 
begin 
  // show up in the Help menu 
  Result := esStandard; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetName: String; 
begin 
  // official name 
  Result := 'Panel Edit Wizard' 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetAuthor: string; 
begin 
  Result := 'Marco and Tim'; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetComment: String; 
begin 
  Result := 'TPanelEditExpert Wizard'; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetPage: string; 
begin 
  Result := ''; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetGlyph: HICON; 
begin 
  Result := 0; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetState: TExpertState; 
begin 
  Result := [esEnabled]; 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetIDString: String; 
begin 
  // must be unique 
  Result := 'DDHandbook.PanelEditWizard' 
end; 

function TPanelEditExpert.GetMenuText: String; 
begin 
  // the text of the menu item 
  Result := '&Panel Edit Wizard' 
end; 

procedure TPanelEditExpert.Execute; 
var 
  ModuleName, FormName, FileName: string; 
  ModIntf: TIModuleInterface; 
begin 
  ToolServices.GetNewModuleAndClassName ( 
    'Panel', ModuleName, FormName, FileName); 
  ModIntf := ToolServices.CreateModuleEx (FileName, FormName, 
    'Panel', '', nil, nil, 
    [cmNewForm, cmAddToProject, cmUnNamed]); 
  ModIntf.ShowSource; 
  ModIntf.ShowForm; 
  ModIntf.Release; 
end; 

// custom module methods 

function TPanelModule.GetVerbCount: Integer; 
begin 
  Result := 1; 
end; 

function TPanelModule.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; 
begin 
  if Index = 0 then 
    Result:= 'Rename...'; 
end; 

procedure TPanelModule.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); 
var 
  NewName: string; 
begin 
  if Index = 0 then 
  begin 
    NewName := Root.Name; 
    if InputQuery ('Panel Module Editor', 
        'New panel name:', NewName) then 
      Root.Name := NewName; 
  end; 
end; 

procedure TPanelModule.ValidateComponent(Component: TComponent); 
begin 
  if not (Component is TButton) and 
      not (Component is TSpeedButton) then 
    raise Exception.Create ('The panel can host only buttons'); 
end; 

procedure Register; 
begin 
  RegisterCustomModule (TPanel, TPanelModule); 
  RegisterLibraryExpert(TPanelEditExpert.Create); 
end; 

end.
```

In the [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Implementing_the_Wizard_Interfaces) I read that I should use a `TNotifierObject` who implements `IOTAWizard` and `IOTAMenuWizard` interfaces (From `ToolsAPI` unit), instead of `ExptIntf` and `ToolsIntf`.

In order to update the example code, I've followed these steps:

1. Removed `ExptIntf` and `ToolsIntf` from source code.
2. Added `ToolsAPI` to the uses clause.
3. Replaced `TExpertState` with `TWizardState`
4. Replaced `esEnabled` with `wsEnabled`.
5. Replaced `RegisterLibraryExpert` with `RegisterPackageWizard`.

After doing this, I still have undeclared identifier errors on `TExpertStyle` and `ToolServices`.

```
function TPanelEditExpert.GetStyle: TExpertStyle; 
begin
  // show up in the Help menu
  Result := esStandard;
end;

procedure TPanelEditExpert.Execute; 
var
  ModuleName, FormName, FileName: string;
  ModIntf: TIModuleInterface;
begin
  ToolServices.GetNewModuleAndClassName (
    'Panel', ModuleName, FormName, FileName); 
  ModIntf := ToolServices.CreateModuleEx (FileName, FormName,
    'Panel', '', nil, nil,
    [cmNewForm, cmAddToProject, cmUnNamed]);
  ModIntf.ShowSource;
  ModIntf.ShowForm;
  ModIntf.Release;
end;
```

How should these parts be updated and/or where can I find an example which don't uses deprecated units?

Comment: You can look at GExperts, it has lot of features, compatible with latest version of Delphi and it is open source project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gexperts

Comment: Asking about downvotes is off topic in a question. I know you are frustrated by the votes, but your edit was not fitting.

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://www.tdug.com/2016/04/april-meeting-follow-up-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Warren Postma spoke at the local Delphi user group in April about creating IDE plug-ins using the Open Tools API.

His [meeting notes](http://www.tdug.com/2016/04/april-meeting-follow-up-2/) are online, including links to his source code.

Note: He was having problems with the parser example, which may or may not be cleaned up in the published sample code.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Links are fine to support an answer, but there should be at leasy the high level information here on site.

Comment: I was responding to the "Where to find" question. Feel free to remove my answer if it violates convention.

Comment: I can't remove it. I'd have to get it to a negative score, and then have it delete voted three times. That's hard to achieve. You could simply delete it and convert it into a comment.